# Opening Java programs in command prompt through SublimeText3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

Similar to TextPad, I want SublimeText3 to open up the command prompt after it compiles the java file. I don't want to run the programs in SublimeText3. I have jdk1.8 and have set up my PATH variable already. It becomes annoying to have to keep typing java and javac.

Press shortcut key(s) -> Sublime compiles and opens command prompt with the program running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up a build system so that Sublime knows how to compile and run your program. You can find more info on that [here](https://gist.github.com/DevinClark/1633819) if you don't know how to do that already.

Comment: I get this error: http://notepad.cc/share/H0UEwZiEEh

I'm using the build dikamilo posted in that link.